# get Current request referer URL and parse it

Tags: php, yii

i have a view (grid) which is used as a rendepatial. this renderpartial grid is used in two actions.

```
<div id="activities"><?php echo $this->renderPartial('grid', array('model'=>$model)); ?></div>
```

i would need to know how can i check which action is requesting now ? i need to stop some scripts generating from yii and add some scripts when action is 'default/index/' (i mean the call is coming from default/index/) this could also be called from this way ... search/default/index/area/act?query=

action A - http://mylocalurl.com/ijob-css/index.php/search/default/index/area/act?query=

action B - http://mylocalurl.com/ijob-css/index.php/activities/default/index/

for action b only i need to add some scripts and wondering how this can be done in yii ?

is there something like this available in yii ? `if(yii->app->getRquest == 'action B')`

**EDIT 1**

I tried it this way,

```
echo Yii::app()->controller->action->id . " - " . Yii::app()->controller->id . " - " . Yii::app()->controller->module->id;
```

it returns, `//sessionIndex - default - activities`  from both actions.

but what i wanted to do is, from where did user come to this path ? his last URL.

so i can easily track weather its action 1 or action 2

**EDIT 2**

tried this way too, echo `Yii::app()->user->returnUrl;`

but it prints onlty - /ijob-css/index.php

**EDIT 3**

This does that but need to know is there any better way to get it ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; also this retuns the entire url like this http://mylocalurl.com/ijob-css/index.php/search/default/index/area/act?query=

but i only needed "search/default/index/area/act?query=" in fact the model id is even fine alone which is "search"

Comment: previous url can be retrieved from Yii::app()->request->getUrlReferrer()

Answer (score 3):

To get action ID use:

```
Yii::app()->controller->action->id
```

Similar for controller:

```
Yii::app()->controller->id
```

And for module use:

```
Yii::app()->controller->module->id
```

You can also use:

```
Yii::app()->request->pathInfo
```

For Yii preprocessed path info

Comment: Nope. it is not i wanted. it returns like this ... echo Yii::app()->controller->action->id . " - " . Yii::app()->controller->id . " - " . Yii::app()->controller->module->id;
      //sessionIndex - default - activities

Comment: You could use `Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer` which actually returns `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. However this looks really sloopy to take samoe action based on referer, perhaps could be used to highlight google search terms.

Comment: can i get only the model->id of what returns from Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer ?

Comment: Theoretically you could use `Yii::app()->urlManager->parseUrl()`, but this is a bit problematic, as `CUrlManager` `parseUrl` method requires request object as param, and always uses current url.

Answer (score 2):

```
$route = Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl(Yii::app()->getRequest());
echo $route;
```

But module, controller, action can be deleted, I advice to give addition parameter to grid

```
$this->renderPartial('grid', compact(
    'model',
    'flag'
));
//grid
switch($flag) {
    ...
}
```